# Modifying lutx function in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is my first question. I am just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

The matrix factorization LU = PA can be used to compute the determinant of A. We have

```
det(L)det(U) = det(P)det(A).
```

Because L is triangular with ones on the diagonal, `det(L) = 1`. Because U is triangular, `det(U) = u 11 u 22 · · · u nn` . Because P is a permutation, `det(P) = +1` if the number of interchanges is even and −1 if it is odd. So `det(A) = ±u 11 u 22 · · · u nn` .

Modify the lutx function so that it returns four outputs.

```
function [L,U,p,sig] = lutx(A)
%LU Triangular factorization
% [L,U,p,sig] = lutx(A) computes a unit lower triangular
% matrix L, an upper triangular matrix U, a permutation
% vector p, and a scalar sig, so that L*U = A(p,:) and
% sig = +1 or -1 if p is an even or odd permutation.
```

Write a function mydet(A) that uses your modified lutx to compute the determinant of A. In Matlab, the product u 11 u 22 · · · u nn can be computed by the expression prod(diag(U)).

I am having trouble getting the function to display all four outputs. I do not understand why the function does not do it automatically. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "display" all four outputs?

Comment: When I call the function it only gives me p and a lower triangular matrix. I cannot get it to show the upper triangular or the sig.

Comment: Did you declare all of your output variables?  My guess is that you're only doing `lutx(A);`.  Try assigning all of the output variables to have places to go: `[L, U, p, sig] = lutx(A);`.  Do that in your command prompt and see what you get.  Specifically, do: `disp(L); disp(U); disp(p); disp(sig);` after calling `[L, U, p, sig] = lutx(A);` when you're done.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I forgot to display them at the end.

Comment: Hahahaha no problem.  I won't even bother writing an answer because the answer was quite trivial.